# On hover toggle children, otherwise first child active

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying basic stuff with jQuery, ugh, I can't make it work.
First paragraph (.active) should be displayed by default. If user is hovering over second, third etc. `li` its `p.box` should be displayed and others hidden.

```
<ul class="list">

  <li>
    <a href="#"> asdf </a>
    <p class="box active">
      lorem ipsum
    </p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#"> asdf 2 </a>
    <p class="box">
      lorem ipsum 2
    </p>
  </li>

</ul>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNjypP

Comment: This is achievable with CSS alone. Why use jQuery? `a+p{display: none;}a:hover+p{display: inline-block;}`

Comment: it is little more complicated so I would prefer to use jQuery, I have removed a lot of unecessary stuff in code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'`hover`' is an event that encapsulates both '`mouseenter`' and '`mouseleave`'. Since you just want to toggle the sections, you should just use '`mouseover`' or '`mouseenter`' delegation. Plus, since you have 2 css classes, make use of it.

```
$(".list li").on('mouseover',function(){        
      $(".list li p.box").removeClass('active').addClass('no');
        $(this).children('p.box').addClass('active');
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/com4k82g/1/

Comment: You should add the `CSS` necessary for this to work too. Remember users seeking the answer to this question are beginners in jQuery (so assuming they are just starting with CSS seems appropriate). Besides, your solution does *not* fully answer the request. The title says: **"otherwise first child active"**.

Answer (score 2):

My proposal is to set for both paragraphs the class to "box no", and to use the jQuery hover function:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".list li").hover(function() {
    $(this).children('p.box').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.no {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list">
    <li>
        <a href="#"> asdf </a>
        <p class="box no">
            lorem ipsum
        </p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"> asdf 2 </a>
        <p class="box no">
            lorem ipsum 2
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery and your current css ie the `no` and `active` classes, try:

```
$(".list li").on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(".list li").children('p.box').removeClass('active').addClass('no');
  $(this).children('p.box').addClass('active').removeClass('no');
});
```

Note the use of `mouseenter` instead of `hover`.

You could set the default `p.box` display to `display:none`, and then you'd just have to add/ remove the one class ie the `active` class.

CSS:

```
p.box {display:none;}
p.box.active {display:block;}
```

and jQuery:

```
$(".list li").on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(".list li").children('p.box').removeClass('active');
  $(this).children('p.box').addClass('active');
});
```

Amending your example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqLmwK

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.list>li').hover(
  function(){
    $('p').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('p').addClass('active')
  },
  function(){
    $(this).find('p').removeClass('active');
    /* next line makes first p be active when no other one is. remove if unwanted */
    $('.list>li:first-child p').addClass('active');
  }
);
```

```css
p {display: none;}
p.active {display: inline;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">

  <li>
    <a href="#"> asdf </a>
    <p class="box active">
      lorem ipsum
    </p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#"> asdf 2 </a>
    <p class="box">
      lorem ipsum 2
    </p>
  </li>

</ul>
```